# How to install flutterfire cli in windows?

Tags: windows, flutter, firebase

I am getting an error while adding firebase to my flutter app using flutterfire cli. I am referencing the official documentation. I have also taken reference from youtube. But still getting that error.
Error is :

> flutterfire : The term 'flutterfire' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
> or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
> correct and try again

I am using windows and vs code.

I have also set the path as well as also checked flutterfire cli. It is installed properly but same error. I have also checked the other solutions on stack overflow for the same problem but none of them worked. I am expecting that to add firebase to my flutter app should be added.

Answer (score 0):

First install Node js at your windows.:[node js](https://nodejs.org/en/download)
Follow proper step to install modems because cli worked on node js.
After that set the path of node at your environment.

When you complete those step then try this command to install cli.

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

then config the cli:

```
flutterfire configure
```

after that you can try other command line flutterfire init or flutterfire login or flutterfire deploy